# Why does JSONB show a different date format than Javascript?

Tags: postgresql, datetime, json, date-format

With Javascript's `.toISOString();` and `.toJSON()` I get

```
(new Date()).toISOString();
2018-01-30T12:04:13.153Z
```

Using PostgreSQL when I return a date, I get

```
# SELECT to_jsonb('2018-01-30T12:04:13.153Z'::timestamp with time zone);
            to_jsonb             
---------------------------------
 "2018-01-30T06:04:13.153-06:00"
(1 row)
```

Why are these two different formats?

Comment: `2018-01-30T07:45:00` **is** an ISO format

Comment: The database when I use RETURN (OBJECT) return me  "2018-01-30T12:04:13.153Z". The Swagger parser don't accept this 2 different formats

Answer (score 3):

With ECMA-262 v6, the `Z` must be present in the result of `.toISOString` if a time zone is provided, you do not need millisecond precision. Javascript on the other hand has no date types to begin with. Both of these formats are [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). PostgreSQL doesn't specify a `Z` and it gives only the precision provided. Nothing prohibits that.

The `Date()` constructor will *gladly* accept both formats, and you should be using [Moment.js for all your date time needs in Javascript.](https://momentjs.com/) You should be immediately constructing date objects with the output of PostgreSQL. This may not be done for you, it also may be something you have to do as JSON doesn't know the difference from a ISO 8601 date/time object, and a string that looks exactly like it. From that point, it's out of PostgreSQL's hand. All that PostgreSQL ensures is that the output is valid JavaScript `Date()` input, which is above and beyond because the JSON spec doesn't even require that.

## ECMA-262 v6 spec,

The [ECMA-262 v6 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/ECMA-262.pdf) says,

> **`Date.prototype.toISOString()`** This function returns a String value representing the instance in time corresponding to this time value. The
>   format of the String is the Date Time string format defined in 20.3.1.16. All fields are present in the String. The time zone is always UTC, denoted by the suffix Z**. If this time value is not a finite Number or if the year is not a value that can be represented in that format (if necessary using extended year format), a RangeError exception is thrown.

That says this,

> `Z` is the time zone offset specified as "Z" (for UTC) or either "+" or "-" followed by a time expression `HH:mm`
>
> This format includes date-only forms:
>
> ```
> YYYY
> YYYY-MM
> YYYY-MM-DD
> ```
>
> It also includes “date-time” forms that consist of one of the above date-only forms immediately followed by one of the following time forms with an optional time zone offset appended:
>
> ```
> THH:mm
> THH:mm:ss
> THH:mm:ss.sss
> ```

## JSON Spec

The JSON spec says nothing about [date formatting](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf). In fact, there isn't even a date type mentioned. This is probably because Javascript dates are [objects not primitives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive).

## PostgreSQL

PostgreSQL outputs only the minimum precision provided to the constructor, and without the `z` (still in ISO 8601).

```
SELECT to_jsonb(dt::timestamp with time zone)
FROM ( VALUES
  ('2018-02-01T13:24:36.466849-06:00'),
  ('2018-02-01T13:24:36-06:00');
```

Comment: In order to execute the PostgreSQL query you need to add an alias at the end, just before the semicolon - `AS foo(dt)`.